# how to get data part by part in S3.getObject(params)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a object from `S3.getObject(params,callback)`

What can I do to choose property by my expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Example your object :

```
let object = {
prop1: value1,
prop2: value2,
prop3: value3
}
```

You can select `value1,value2` by

```
let newObject = {
value1: object.value1,
value2: object.value2
}
```

Is this your problem ?

Comment: Actually I am trying s3.getObject(params).S3 bucket contains huge csv file.I want to read the data from the csv file and then push it to DynamoDb.Since the data is huge so its pushing only some data to dynamoDb and then it breaks with JavaScript heap out of memory error

Comment: I have some confuse with your problem. But I think you should devide your process step by step and `async` to catch issue each step. Goodluck.